# Count rows and copy number

Tags: excel, vba, count, macros, paste

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets with tables in the range **from A to L**. I want to count the rows and paste the result into a summary sheet.

For example:

Sheet2 has 3 rows. I want to copy the number of rows into sheet1 C3

Sheet3 has 9 rows. I want to copy the number of rows into sheet1 C4

Sheet4 has 5 rows. I want to copy the number of rows into sheet1 C5

and so on through all my sheets. (I have over 3000 sheets)

I am new to macro in excel so I would appreciete any help, thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a "Code for me" site nor is it a "Teach me to code" site.  It is a site dedicated to helping find the errors in existing code and overcome those problems.

Answer (score 2):

No macro needed just us a formula:

`=COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)`  changing sheet2 to the approrpiate sheet for each cell in C3, C4, C5

Put simply...put

`=COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)` in C3

`=COUNTA(Sheet3!A:A)` in C4

`=COUNTA(Sheet4!A:A)` in C5

Assuming Column A in each sheet has a value when you want to count the row, otherwise use a different column! (changing A:A to B:B or something else)

If the names aren't sheet1 etc... you could....

Create this defined name:
Formulas tab > Name Manager > New

- Name: SheetNames
- Scope: Workbook
- Refers to: =GET.WORKBOOK(1)&T(NOW())
- click OK

Then add this formula to B instead of the numbers

`=INDEX(MID(SheetNames,FIND("]",SheetNames)+1,255),ROWS(A$1:A1))`

Fill down and now you have the values to fill in your c3 and beyond

Comment: `(I have over 3000 sheets)` that is going to take a little time. :)  lets say 10 second per formula 3000*10 / 60 = 500 minutes or 8 1/3 hours.  I would get a list of sheets, there are many sites that will show how to do this using a named range.  Then use INDIRECT inside the COUNTA that will reference so the formula can be filled down.  Just an observation.  I like the approach.

Comment: then I'd use a formula in A such as ="=CountA(Sheet"&B3000&"!A:A)" and in B put 1-3000 using a fill series.. Then derive all the values to paste in... done in a few seconds; but your point is well made.  my approach is defiantly not dynamic. and full of assumptions

Comment: That would work if the sheet names are are all `Sheet` and some number, and be quicker on the recalc.

Comment: Dang it... Excel expert I'm proving I"m not... but I'll keep learning @ScottCraner

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I managed to get it working for the first cell with: =COUNTIF('30146A000A'!A3:A2001,"<>"&"")

Because the sheets are not named "Sheet1" etc, I had to type in the name (in this case "30146A000A"). Any idea of how I could simplify the process. I tried using =COUNTIF(Sheet(2) !A3:A2001,"<>"&"")
but that did not work.

Comment: Updated answer based on info found: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/428957-list-worksheet-names-using-formula.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this simple macro helps:

```
Sub coutndisplay()

    Dim count As Integer

    ' Create an object for sheet 1
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ' Get the number of sheets in the workbook
    count = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count

    For i = 2 To count

        ' Populate the number of rows in sheet 1 starting from C3
        ' C3 populate the number of rows in sheet 2 and it goes on
        sh1.Cells(i + 1, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.count
    Next i

End Sub
```